# Church Numerals in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, type-inference, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I have been trying to implement church numerals in F#. They were briefly introduced in a course at college and I may have gone down the rabbit hole a bit since then. I have working Predecessor, Successor, Add and Operations but I can't get subtract to work. I'm trying to implement subtract b applying predecessor multiple times. What I find peculiar is that the penultimate line in my code works but what I assume is equivalent, the last line, does not work. There is a type mismatch.

I'm very new to F# so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
//Operations on tuples
let fst (a,b) = a
let snd (a,b) = b
let pair a b = (a,b)

//Some church numerals
let c0 (f:('a -> 'a)) = id
let c1 (f:('a -> 'a)) = f 
let c2 f = f << f
let c3 f = f << f << f
let c4 f = f << f << f << f

// Successor and predecessor
let cSucc (b,(cn:('a->'a)->('a->'a))) = if b then (b, fun f -> f << (cn f)) else (true, fun f -> (cn f))
let cPred (cn:('a->'a)->('a->'a)) = fun f -> snd (cn cSucc (false, c0)) f
//let cSucc2 cn = fun f -> f << (cn f)

// Add, Multiply and Subtract church numerals
let cAdd cn cm = fun f -> cn f << cm f
let cMult cn cm = cn >> cm
let cSub cn cm = cm cPred cn

//Basic function for checking validity of numeral operations
let f = (fun x -> x + 1)

//This works
(cPred << cPred) c3 f 0

//This doesn't
c2 cPred c3 f 0
```

This is the type mismatch error given (Intellisense says this is an error with cPred on the last line of the code). I can see the output type is inferred wrong. Is there a way to fix it or is there something fundamentally wrong with how I have written this implementation?

```
'((bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a) -> bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a)) -> bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a) -> bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a)) -> (bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a) -> bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a)) -> bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a) -> bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a)'    
but given a
    '((bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a) -> bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a)) -> bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a) -> bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a)) -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a'    
The types ''a' and 'bool * (('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a)' cannot be unified.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the below explanation I will assume a definition of `type CN<'a> = ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a` (where "CN" stands for "Church Numeral") in order to shorten the explanation and reduce clutter.

Your attempted application of `c2` to `cPred` fails, because `c2` expects an argument of type `'a -> 'a`, but `cPred` is not such function.

You may expect `cPred` to match the expected type, because you have declared it as `CN<'a> -> CN<'a>`, but that is not the true type. Because you are applying argument `cn` to type `bool*CN<'a> -> bool*CN<'a>` (which is the type of `cSucc`), the compiler infers that `cn` must have type of `CN<bool*CN<'a>>`, and therefore `cPred` gets the type of `CN<bool*CN<'a>> -> CN<'a>`, which does not match what `c2` expects.

All of this comes down to this fact: *functions lose their genericity when you pass them around as values*.

Consider a simpler example:

```
let f (g: 'a -> 'a list) = g 1, g "a"
```

Such definition will not compile, because `'a` is a parameter of `f`, not a parameter of `g`. Therefore, for a given execution of `f`, a specific `'a` must be chosen, and it cannot be both `int` and `string` at the same time, and therefore, `g` cannot be applied to both `1` and `"a"`.

Similarly, `cn` in `cPred` gets fixed to type `bool*CN<'a> -> bool*CN<'a>`, thus making the type of `cPred` itself incompatible with `CN<_>`.

In simple cases, there is an obvious workaround: pass `g` twice.

```
let f g1 g2 = g1 1, g2 "a"
let g x = [x]
f g g
// > it : int list * string list = [1], ["a"]
```

This way, `g` will lose genericity both times, but it will be specialized to different types - the first instance to `int -> int list`, the second - to `string -> string list`.

However, this is only a half-measure, suitable for the simplest cases only. A general solution will require the compiler to understand that we want `'a` to be a parameter of `g`, not a parameter of `f` (this is usually referred to as ["higher-rank type"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types)). In Haskell (more specifically, GHC), there is a [straightforward way to do this](https://repl.it/repls/MeekSurefootedRoadrunner), with the `RankNTypes` extension enabled:

```
f (g :: forall a. a -> [a]) = (g 1, g "a")
g x = [x]
f g
==> ([1], ["a"])
```

Here, I explicitly tell the compiler that the parameter `g` has its own generic parameter `a` by including `forall a` in its type declaration.

F# does not have such explicit support for this, but it does offer a different feature that can be used to accomplish the same result - interfaces. Interfaces may have generic methods, and these methods do not lose genericity when interface instances are passed around. So we can reformulate the above simple example like this:

```
type G = 
    abstract apply : 'a -> 'a list

let f (g: G) = g.apply 1, g.apply "a"
let g = { new G with override this.apply x = [x] }
f g
// it : int list * string list = ([1], ["a"])
```

Yes, the syntax for declaring such "higher-rank functions" is heavy, but that's all F# has to offer.

So, applying this to your original problem, we need to declare `CN` as an interface:

```
type CN = 
    abstract ap : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
```

Then we can construct some numbers:

```
let c0 = { new CN with override __.ap f x = x }
let c1 = { new CN with override __.ap f x = f x }
let c2 = { new CN with override __.ap f x = f (f x) }
let c3 = { new CN with override __.ap f x = f (f (f x)) }
let c4 = { new CN with override __.ap f x = f (f (f (f x))) }
```

Then `cSucc` and `cPred`:

```
let cSucc (b,(cn:CN)) = 
    if b 
    then (b, { new CN with override __.ap f x = f (cn.ap f x) }) 
    else (true, cn)

let cPred (cn:CN) = snd (cn.ap cSucc (false, c0))
```

Note that `cPred` now has inferred type of `CN -> CN`, exactly what we need.
Arithmetic functions:

```
let cAdd (cn: CN) (cm: CN) = { new CN with override __.ap f x = cn.ap f (cm.ap f x) }
let cMult (cn: CN) (cm: CN) = { new CN with override __.ap f x = cn.ap cm.ap f x }
let cSub (cn: CN) (cm: CN) = cm.ap cPred cn
```

Note, all of them get the inferred type of `CN -> CN -> CN`, as expected.

And finally, your examples:

```
let f = (fun x -> x + 1)

//This works
((cPred << cPred) c3).ap f 0

//This also works now
(c2.ap cPred c3).ap f 0
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I notice you defined the Church numerals as functions applied multiple times to an argument x. Is this a better idea than the <<s I used?

Comment: It makes no difference. You can say `f (f x)` or `(f << f) x`, the resulting compiled code would be the same. Matter of private taste.